# Fill large gap in plaster with no lath

Tags: plaster

An electrician recently replaced the electrical panel in my apartment and left an inch-wide gap in the plaster along one side of the box. Unfortunately, they had to cut through the lath, so there is no backing for a repair patch.

I've included two pictures below.

Any thoughts on how to approach a repair would be appreciated, and please let me know if you have other questions that might be relevant.

Thanks!

[image]

[image: Gap in plaster]

Comment: Just spray expanding foam into the gap. Let it harden and then dig out enough to fill the  area with plaster/drywall mud. The foam will create a rigid connection with everything so may get away without the need for taping.

Comment: Are you the landlord or a tenant?

Comment: I own the apartment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll up some fiberglas insulation like a jelly roll, so you can stuff it into the opening. Keep it recessed about one-half inch, so it acts like a foam backer except non-combustible. Make it a tight fit. Remove the front cover if you prefer, and tape a piece of heavy plastic over the electricals so you can just access the gap.
Fill the new gap with plaster or drywall compound, flush with the existing wallboard. A masking tape barrier will keep the mud from touching the panel box. Re-install the front cover, then sand and paint to match.

Answer (score 1):

How about skip the plaster and get a couple pieces of wood trim to cover the gap and frame the panel?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to what John said above with the addition of scrunched up metal mesh to give the plaster something to grab hold of.

Or alternatively for a quick fix, you could fill the gap with insulation and then tack wooden cover trims either side to blend in with the existing wood work below and above, paint them white and the jobs done.

BTW, nice work from the electrician (and yes, I'm being sarcastic...).